# Check PayPal payment status by item number

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a website that accepts PayPal payments and I need to check old payments (like a week ago) that
appear pending on my server.

Since payments are "pending" on my server I don't have the PayPal transaction id to identify then on PayPal servers so I need another way to search for them, for example, using the "item number" that corresponds to the payment id on my site.

The final idea is to have a cron job that runs every day and checks for pending payments and retrieve their status on PayPal and try to confirm them automatically.

Is there a way to check a payment status using PayPal's api by the item number or other field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier system to check on payments that are made through them and that is the Paypal IPN API.

[Paypal IPN API Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) should get you started and up and running.

Inside of the provided code from the IPN API, they have multiple methods to check for payments and if they are paid, pending, denied, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried sending an IPN message to PayPal with the field item_number but I receive an INVALID response. All examples use many fields, such as transaction id, which I don't have, payment_status, mc_gross, etc.

Comment: Paypal IPN is, well, its an ass. You HAVE to read the documentation on it to get everything just right. There are a few good tutorials out there but even those still make you read the documentation. It sucks but this is the best way to do what you are asking.

Comment: Ok I'll keep trying then. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't be discouraged though. It took me quite a bit of time to get this working the way that I needed it to work but the tutorials online helped out a bunch in getting started. Good luck!